# Datatable size change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I am using jquery datatable and I need to contain the table inside a container

for now the table width exceedthe container

I tried the following

1- set the `sWidth` option on the `table` and on the `columns`

3- set the `bAutoWidth` to false

2- change the value of `dataTables_wrapper`

nothing works

my code look like this

the JS

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
                    .fromSource('api/fromRest')


$scope.dtColumns = [
                    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstCol').withTitle('first')
.....
```

the HTML

```
<table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns"
   dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs">
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

create a css file and set width

html structure

```
<div id="container">
<div id="table"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#table{
width: 600px !important;
}
```

Alternative

```
    <div id="container">
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    </div>
```

It will automatically set `width` to your `container` div. If it does not work, please show me full html code

Comment: Please create a snippet. You can paste your code, add the jQuery script, and show live what the bug is :)

Comment: What worked best on me is set `width` to controller and then `width="100%"` on table.

Answer (score 0):

Two things spring to mind - firstly are you calling fnAdjustColumnSizing whenthe table is made visible, and do you have a CSS declaration something like table { width: 100% }?

Comment: I don't know what's  fnAdjustColumnSizing, and if I have a CSS declaration  is there a way to overwrite it for the datatable ?

Comment: I just found out what fnAdjustColumnSizing , and no I don't use it.

Comment: You need to try this. Be more helpful to understand us what exactly you want! I will be happy to help!